# Create custom splash screen in Firefox OS application

Tags: splash-screen, firefox-os

After developing an application, Firefox OS automatically creates a splash screen for the app using the app icon. But for my application I want to develop a custom splash screen.

It is possible using  JavaScript methods like  But firefox `setTimeOut` or `setInterval`, but Firefox OS doesn’t support these types of methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can create 2 pages and after your desired time, just switch to another page using javascript. You should put the first page in manifest.

Comment: how i passed that desired time caused setTimeout or setInterval both are break the content security policy of firefox OS